# How to get the time information from a video of varying frame rate using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, video, video-streaming, computer-vision, video-processing

I have a video in which the frame rate is not constant over the length of video. How can i get the actual time information from the video using MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `mmread()` available from the file exchange: [(link)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread). More generally, the best way is to be using a Unix system and issue system calls to a better program, like ffmpeg or mencoder, which can give you frame-specific timing information. Doing this with Matlab only would be a real pain. There may be a toolbox function for it, but then your code only works for other people who also have the toolbox...